# Matlab if/for-Statement Assign Value

Tags: matlab, if-statement, comparison

I have an `if` statement something like

```
t(2,5)
P(6,1)

if x:length(t)

t(2,3)>P
P=0
elseif t(2,3)<P
P=1

end
```

---

basically what I want to achieve is a loop that runs through t and compares it to p, if the value of t is smaller than the value of P a new matrix should be created and record the value as "1", if the value of t is bigger than the value of P record value as "0", I can't get it to work unfortunately.

Comment: If it helped you, it is helpful. Consider accepting the answers as valid, you will gain reputation and make sure that people will help you in the future, as accepting teh answer that helped you is the way of saying "thank you" in Stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to check if the values in array/matrix `t` is less than a certain constant value, say `P`, then better run `t<P`. That will do the job.
If `t` and `P` are both matrices, of equal length, then also you can use `t<P`. No need for loops or `if` statements.

Comment: but i want to create a new matrix that saved the values if t>p "0", if t<p "1", it has to check each row of t and compare it to p

Comment: That is exactly what will happen here. Allot the output to a variable say **X** . So your code will look like `X=(t<P)`.